# python: find value within range in float array

Tags: python, floating-point, intervals

I have the following sorted python list, although multiple values can occur:

```
[0.0943200769115388, 0.17380131294164516, 0.4063245853719435, 
 0.45796523225774904, 0.5040225609708342, 0.5229351852840304, 
 0.6145136350368882, 0.6220712583558284, 0.7190096076050408, 
 0.8486436998476048, 0.8957381707345986, 0.9774325873910711, 
 0.9832076130275351, 0.985386554764682, 1.0]
```

Now, I want to know the index in the array where a particular value may fall:

For example, a value of 0.25 would fall in index `2` because it is between 0.173 and 0.40. I guess I can go through the list and do this in a for loop but I was wondering if there is some better way to do this which maybe more computationally efficient. I create this array once but have to perform many lookups.

Comment: Here ya go: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html

Comment: **Is the float range you're testing fixed or variable?** If it's fixed, you can quantize each value into a range when you insert it.

Comment: If you even have any statistical information about the range of queries you expect to get (e.g. +FLT_MAX..-FLT_MAX), you can bin them into some range. Or you could create a reverse data-structure which maps value -> index, or bin -> index

Comment: The float range is between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Luca You deleted question, but keep in mind that `NUMBER` is datatype not part of column name

Comment: I figured that out...smacked myself in the head and deleted the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> vals = [0.0943200769115388, 0.17380131294164516, 0.4063245853719435, 
 0.45796523225774904, 0.5040225609708342, 0.5229351852840304, 
 0.6145136350368882, 0.6220712583558284, 0.7190096076050408, 
 0.8486436998476048, 0.8957381707345986, 0.9774325873910711, 
 0.9832076130275351, 0.985386554764682, 1.0]

>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect(vals, 0.25)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the list is already sorted, then the textbook solution is to do a binary search.  You keep two index bounds, min and max.  Initialize them to 0 and len - 1.  Then set mid to be (min + max) / 2.  Compare the value at index mid with your target value.  If it's less, then set min to mid + 1.  If it's greater, then set max to mid - 1.  Repeat until you either find the value or until max < min, in which case you will have found the desired index in O(log(n)) steps.